# Why would ftp_connect() return false on production server if it works elsewhere for connecting to the same FTP server?

Tags: php, ftp

I have a script that uses `ftp_connect()` among other FTP PHP functions for uploading a file.

`ftp_connect()` works when executed on my local development server for connecting to a remote FTP server. The same script, when executed on the remote server does not work for connecting to the exact same FTP server.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
$server = 'ftp.someserver.com';
$ftpConn = ftp_connect($server);
if(!$ftpConn)
    echo 'failed';
else
    echo 'success';
```

No errors are reported.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly then the script above is installed on the server that you're trying to access using FTP (ie. the script is opening a local FTP connection)? What's the use? FTP in PHP is only useful to transfer files between 2 servers, you cannot use it to transfer files from the client to the server (since the script is executed on the server).

Comment: Hmm. well thanks that is great to know. I had originally decided to use PHP FTP functions so 1) I could learn them, and 2) To prepare for a multiple file upload script down the road, but it looks like I should have done my homework on that one. I ended up using `move_uploaded_file()` and it is working. If you put your response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand it correctly then the script above is installed on the server that you're trying to access using FTP (ie. the script is opening a local FTP connection)? What's the use? FTP in PHP is only useful to transfer files between 2 servers, you cannot use it to transfer files from the client to the server (since the script is executed on the server).

**edit**

Something I didn't add in my original comment : you could use a Java FTP applet if you want to transfer files from the client to the server. But be aware of the security issues involved (because the user credentials can be sniffed :p).

Answer (score 2):

Probably firewall issues. On top of that, FTP was not designed with NAT in mind.

Try to login to the production server and use a ftp client to do the same connection.

Comment: I am able to log in to the same FTP server via FireFTP with the same credentials.

Comment: @letseatfood From the production server? Another thing: increase the error_reporting level in PHP and see what the error message is.

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean for me to log in via the shell and use ftp? I am still new to this. Usually I use an ftp client on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the things inside it very well but I want to give my little help.My server is ubuntu Linux with Apache、PHP and MySQL,and my develop env is MAMP on Mac.

1. I met the problem suddenly and cannot find what happened because it was worked yesterday,I searched many answers and can't solved it.The `ftp_connect($ftp_server)` only return `bool(false)`,but I can use my FileZilla,interesting,is it?
2. So I try to connect the server from my command line,like `ftp 111.22.333.44`,It shows:

   500 OOPS: cannot read user list file:/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.user_list
3. I login in my ubuntu server, and didn't find the `vsftpd` directory,and the `vsftpd.user_list`is in the directory `/etc/`,still don't know what happened.
4. So I simply create the directory and copy the file `vsftpd.user_list` to it.Then I try `ftp 111.22.333.44(your IP address)` again  and it works now.

hope it help someone else.